# Thickness of the partition wall made of plasterboard

Tags: drywall, partition

We are renovating our apartment and decided to change all partition walls, as the existing ones were only 50 mm thick with no sound isolation within and with no vertical fixation.

We were surprised to learn that in France, standard partition walls are **72 mm thick** (13+46+13), compared to (at least) 100 mm thick plasterboard walls in other countries.

**What are advantages of having thicker partition walls?**

Comment: More room for insulation? Bats are around 45mm?

Comment: @Tim It crossed my mind, could it be the only reason? 45 mm insulation fits within 46 mm frame.

Comment: Check sizes at Bricomarche, etc. If sold like that, it's a good reason.

Comment: Leroy Merlin sells frames in many different sizes (32, 34, 46, 70, 100). All new buildings seem to have 46 mm frames, whereas where I come from we use 70 mm or even 100 mm frames. I am just wondering what is the main reason; could it be to fit more insulation, or there is something more to it?

Comment: More soundproofing insulation. Maybe better fire resistance between rooms. Maybe local custom. Did you ask at the store what the advantages of the different thicknesses were?

Comment: It's a tradeoff, as most things are. Thicker walls take up more of your valuable internal space, thinner walls take up less of it. Thicker walls can offer better sound insulation, and are stronger (but these are non-structural partition walls, so "stronger" is of limited value.)

Comment: I would add thermal insulation as an added boon. If you keep different temperature zones in the house, more thickness would reduce your energy usage a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. Thermals is of no concern for me as I have central (building) heating everywhere. I only care about sound isolation, but it does not have to be perfect, so I'll go with 72 mm thickness. It will make my life easier since most of the door frames are available for 72 mm wall thickness anyway.

Comment: Fyi, temperature zones are also commonly applied in buildings with central heating (by using the radiator valves). We keep the living room warm and the bedroom cold this way.

Comment: @MiG That is true, but I do not see added benefit of putting thicker partition wall at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> standard partition walls are 72 mm thick (13+46+13),

Yes, that is the cheapest option.

If you read French, you can search various construction methods [here](https://www.placo.fr/cloisons-0).

The height of your partition wall sets the minimum stud width. If your ceiling is at 3m, 70mm studs are recommended. For 2.40m ceiling, the standard  48mm studs are adequate. Higher walls need thicker studs to avoid bowing at mid-height. So if you have a mezzanine or high ceilings, you must factor this in the design.

Then, for partition walls, the next criteria will be soundproofing. There is really no other reason to make the wall thicker, besides running pipes through them. Partition walls usually don't play a role in thermal insulation, so that's not a reason to make them thicker.

But... soundproofing is really important.

The most important step is to use a double set of studs: each side of the wall gets its own set of studs, so when sound from one room hits the side of the wall in this room, it doesn't transfer directly to the other side of the wall through the studs.

[image]

Typical construction would be a 70mm rail, which is normally used for 70mm studs, with two sets of 48mm studs, one set per side. So you get 70+13x2=96mm thickness. Or two 48mm rails, as shown on the above picture, which gives 48x2+13x2=122mm.

Two independent sets of studs brings the most return on investment for soundproofing. It's not much more expensive, but it really works. Construction needs special care though, especially for electrical sockets: if you make holes in both sides of the wall right in front of each other for sockets, then noise will go straight through. You have to position the holes with care so they don't face each other.

However, since the studs are supported only on one side by the drywall, the rules for stud width are different, so make sure you read the documentation.

Then, to get even better soundproofing, you can use wider studs, to make it more rigid.

You can also add mass by using heavier drywall, or two layers of it on each side. In the latter case, a viscoelastic damping compound (aka acrylic caulk) can be applied between the layers to dampen vibrations. An example build would be 70mm rail, two sets of 48mm studs, and two layers of drywall on each side. That would give 70+13x4=122mm thickness, with good soundproofing.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable and detailed answer, now I understand the differences. In my home country, the ceiling is typically at 2.60 m or 2.70 m, and in France the ceiling is typically at 2.50 m or even 2.40 m. This might be the main reason why 46 mm rails are used in France. *When in Rome, do as the Romans do*, so I'll probably go with 72 mm thickness. Most of the door frames here are available for 72 mm wall thickness anyway.

Comment: Yup. Note thicker studs do next to nothing for soundproofing, so if you want soundproofing, use two independent sets.

Comment: I do not care for perfect soundproofing, if I do two independent sets then the doors will be the critical points. I'll build a regular single set partition wall (72 mm) and put some stone wool from within for better soundproofing. Thanks!

Comment: Would you please expound on the math in the paragraph just below the picture. In my math book, `70+132=96mm` isn't correct, nor is `482+13*2=122mm`. Either there are some typos in there, or you're doing something I really don't understand, so an explanation of where these numbers come from and how they add up to what you say they add up to would greatly improve the answer.

Comment: @FreeMan Notice that numbers are in italic. bobflux used * (asterisk) character for multiplication, and when you put something in between these two characters, they become italicized. I fixed it now by replacing asterisks with x (times).

Comment: Ah! Excellent @Marko. Thank you. I've approved your edit, but it will take one other person to approve it before it will appear for everyone. Also, you could have surrounded the math with "backtick" marks to make it appear exactly as written (usually used for code, but highlights it as it appears in my comment above).

Comment: @FreeMan I know about the "backtick", I am also using it in these situations. In the edit I wanted to keep as much as possible from the original author's formatting :)

Comment: Oh, right, I got caught by the * italics again. Thanks for fixing it.